# Web based 3D Scatter Plot

Tags: jquery, charts, dojo

Is there any java script library out there that lets you create a 3D scatter plot? 
Preferably one that lets the user interact with it (pan, rotate, zoom, etc)

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? Please vote the answer or post what you find to resolve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see http://www.canvasxpress.org/scatter3d.html?

The home page is http://www.canvasxpress.org/

I hope it helps.